# Док, верф, корабельня. Чи є різниця?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, етимологія, запозичені-слова

[Док](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=23455&page=793):

> ДОК, у, чол. Портова споруда для **ремонту** суден, а ***іноді*** і їх будування.

[Корабельня](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=44049&page=1393):

> КОРАБЕ́ЛЬНЯ, і, жін. Сукупність споруд для **будування та ремонту** кораблів; верф.

[Верф](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=7595&page=280):

> ВЕРФ, і, ж. 1. Підприємство для **будівництва і ремонту** суден.

Має сенс припустити, що корабельня і верф - це одне й те саме (але я невпевнений, якби хтось мав спростування - я б залюбки почитав його). А ось чи відрізняються вони від доку, чи верф і док - це просто запозичення з різних мов?

Answer (score 4):

Док - споруда в яку може запливти корабель. Він може бути осушенимй ("сухий док"), або навіть плавучим і використовуватись для транспортування кораблів. Верф призначена для збору кораблів з нуля з подальшим спуском на воду. Краще відчути різницю у використанні термінів можна якщо порівняти голладські слова [Droogdok](http://%22https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droogdok) (сухий док) та [Scheepswerf](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheepswerf) (корабельна верф) від яких через російску й було, скоріш за все, запозичено "док" і "верф".
Корабельня ж вживається більше в розумінні саме підприємства яке може мати кілька доків, майстерні й склади.